# Error: Sole tenant instances must have at least 2 cores

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I recently started to get this error after running a gcloud script to create a new instance on GCE to be a part of an instance group. The problem is that it worked in the past, is it a policy change by Google? Also, what part of the command implies that I ask for sole tenant nodes? Is there a way to change it to a shared instance?
Here is the command line I use:

```
gcloud compute instances create callback-server ^
--image-family=debian-9 ^
--image-project=debian-cloud ^
--machine-type=g1-small ^
--zone=us-central1-f ^
--scopes=userinfo-email,cloud-platform ^
--metadata-from-file=startup-script=startup-script.sh ^
--tags=http-server,https-server ^
--node-group=callback-server-group
```

And here is the output:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Sole tenant instances must have at least 2 cores.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the [--node-group option](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--node-group). This option specifies the node group for [sole tenant nodes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/create-nodes#create). (ie. it's **not** a synonym for managed instance group)

To add instances to an instance group:

- For **managed** instance groups, [resize the group](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/resize) to the desired number.
- For **unmanaged** instance groups, use [gcloud compute instance-groups unmanaged add-instances](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/unmanaged/add-instances).